# Vanilla C drop in replacement for intel intrinsics?

Tags: c, simd, intrinsics, avx

For each avx, sse4 etc intrinsic there is an open logical algorithm. I wonder if there is an official or unofficial drop in replacement of intrinsics with vanilla C code (for debugging, prototyping on arm etc)?

Comment: If there was, what do you want to do?

Comment: Each project that might need some or all of these will eventually implement it. Does it count as official/unofficial drop?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: if it publishes it as something usable in stand-alone from the main project mode

Comment: Some of them are borderline impossible to emulate precisely: `rcpps`, `rsqrtps` use undocumented approximations, `vfmadd132pd` needs 128 bit floats. Basic math is simple but very slow: if the source code mixes floats and doubles, and you’re emulating SSE with legacy x87 instructions, you’ll need to switch precision in FP control register before every instruction.

Comment: @Soonts:  very slow is what is expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a project, [SIMDe](https://github.com/nemequ/simde/), that does it.  It's not complete, but it's more substantial than [anything else I'm aware of](https://github.com/nemequ/simde/#related-projects).  Contributions welcome ;)